# How to prevent password reset email from being sent when creating new user in API

Tags: apex, api

How to prevent password reset email from being sent when creating new user in API.  Basically I'll be provisioning users via the API but because they are logging in via SSO, I don't want to send them a welcome email?  How can I programatically prevent the password reset email from being sent?

Thanks
BY

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want the DMLOption for [triggerUserEmail](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_Database_EmailHeader.htm#apex_Database_EmailHeader_triggerUserEmail).

From the documentation:

> This email can be automatically triggered by a number of events; resetting a password, **creating a new user**, or creating or modifying a task.

So, if you set this to false the email shouldn't go out.

The same option is also available in the Partner API via the [EmailHeader Soap Header](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_header_emailheader.htm#triggeruseremail).